# Cucumber - WebDriverWait null pointer exception - Java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, pageobjects

I am trying to integrate Cucumber Framework to existing automation framework. Something that I can't understand that each call the method WaitForElement, it gives me a null pointer exception. Maybe someone can explain where I am doing it wrong.

Following is my TestStep class

```
package Steps;
import TestFramework.*;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyStepdefs extends BaseStep{
private WebDriver driver = null;
private Hooks lHooks;
private SceanarioContext sceanarioContext;
private WebDriverWait wait;


public MyStepdefs(Hooks lHooks, Hooks lwait, SceanarioContext sceanarioContext) {
    this.driver = lHooks.driver;
    this.wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    this.sceanarioContext=sceanarioContext;
}

@Given("The user login to the application")
public void the_user_login_to_the_application() {
    LoginPage loginObject = new LoginPage(driver,wait);
    resultValue = loginObject.VerifyUrl();
    resultMessage = "URL is verified";
    Assert.assertTrue(resultMessage,resultValue);
}    
}
```

Following is my BaseStep class which is extended by Mysteps.

```
package Steps;

import Pages.BasePage;
import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

 public class BaseStep{
public WebDriver driver = null;
public long explicitWaitValue = 10;
public WaitHelper wait;
public Boolean resultValue;
public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BasePage.class);
public String resultMessage="";
public Object scenarioContextObject;

public String GetTableValues(String headerValue, DataTable dataTable) {
    List<Map<String, String>> data = dataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
    String value = data.get(0).get(headerValue);
    return value;
}
}
```

Following is my Hooks class which does the browser and driver instantiation. I have declared Pages in this class which is in the src/Pages packages to share the instantiation of the Webdriver and WebdriverWait class. I cannot extend Hooks class in BaseStep class as it does not allow me to do so.

```
package Steps;

import Pages.Page;
import TestFramework.ConfigFileReader;
import TestFramework.ManageWebDriver;
import io.cucumber.core.api.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.property.PrimitivePropertyBuilders;

public class Hooks {
protected static WebDriver driver = null;
public static WebDriverWait wait =null;
protected static Page page;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    ConfigFileReader configFileReader = new ConfigFileReader();
    String browserName = configFileReader.getDefaultBrowser();
    ManageWebDriver manage = new ManageWebDriver();
    this.driver = manage.GetBrowser(browserName);
    driver.get(configFileReader.getApplicationUrl());
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    page = new Page(driver,wait);
}
@After
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png"); //stick it in the report
    }
    driver.close();
}

}
```

Following is my LoginPage class which is called in my Steps to perform functionalities

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginPage extends BasePage{


WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;
Boolean url = false;


public LoginPage(WebDriver driver,WebDriverWait wait) {
    super(driver,wait);
    this.driver = driver;
    this.wait=wait;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, wait);
}

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "username")
private WebElement loginEmail;
public boolean VerifyUrl(){
    WaitUntilElement(loginEmail);
    if(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("auth"))
        return url=true;
    return false;
}
}
```

Following is my BasePage class which is extended by the LoginPage. This is where the problem happens. I do get a value for wait when I debug. But when the WaitUntilElement is called, it gives a Null Pointer exception

```
package Pages;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

public class BasePage extends Page {
public WebDriver driver = null;
public long explicitWaitValue = 10;
public Boolean resultValue;
public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BasePage.class);
public String resultMessage="";
public Object scenarioContextObject;

public BasePage(WebDriver driver,WebDriverWait wait) {
    super(driver,wait);
    this.driver = driver;
    this.wait=wait;
}
public void WaitUntilElement(WebElement element){
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}
}
```

Following is the Page class which gets the value of driver and wait when it is instantiated in the Hooks class. This in turn is extended by BasePage

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Page {
public WebDriver driver;
public WebDriverWait wait;

public Page(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait){
    this.driver = driver;
    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
}
}
```

I have tried instantiating the WebDriver in BasePage and Page as well. But somehow it gives me a null pointer exception always.

I am new to the implementation of Cucumber with Java hence maybe I am missing something minute or maybe something major which I am not able to find out. It would be brilliant to know where I am making the mistake.

Comment: Add the stack trace . Are you using cucumber-picocontainer ?

Comment: @Rahul L yes. I am using cucumber-picoconatiner.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:103)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:92)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:79)
 at Pages.LoginPage.<init>(LoginPage.java:20)
 at Steps.MyStepdefs.the_user_login_to_the_application(MyStepdefs.java:35)

Comment: In login page constructor change this line - PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

Comment: @Rahul it still gives me an error. I tried debugging to find out the problem. In my Before method in Hooks, I am able to instantiate driver and wait for Page class. For the first instance it associates a value like WebDriverWait as 3353 but then it calls again the constructor and assigns another value to WebDriver wait as 3327 . I am sure that there is some sort of mistake in the Page class constructor. I also tried changing here as this.wait = wait but it does not help. NPE always!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My driver was null in the arguments being passed to webdriver wait. I put if statement to check if driver is null and it is. so initiated the page class where driver was setup and it is fixed. Message me if still stuck